# How can I download multiple PDF files with Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to download the publications on every page of https://occ.ca/our-publications

My end goal is to parse through the text in the PDF files and locate certain keywords.

Thus far, I have been able to scrape the links to the PDF files on all the pages. I have saved these links into a list. Now, I want to go through the list and download all the pdf files with Python. Once the files have been downloads, I want to parse through them.

This is the code that I have used thus far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import csv

# This code adds all PDF links into a list called 
#"publications".

publications=[]
for i in range(19):
    response=requests.get('https://occ.ca/our- 
   publications/page/{}/'.format(i), headers={'User- 
    Agent': 'Mozilla'})

    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        pdfs = soup.findAll('div', {"class": 
       "publicationoverlay"})
        links = [pdf.find('a').attrs['href'] for pdf in pdfs]
    publications.append(links)
```

## Next, I want to go through that list and download the PDF files.

```
import urllib.request
for x in publications:
urllib.request.urlretrieve(x,'Publication_{}'.format(range(213)))
```

This is the error I get when I run the code.

## This is the error I get

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\plumm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\m.py", line 23, in 
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(x,'Publication_ {}.pdf'.format(range(213)))
  File "C:\Users\plumm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Users\plumm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\plumm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\plumm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\plumm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\plumm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\plumm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Comment: Do you want a hierachical list or just a flat list of links?
If you want a flat links of list, then you shouldn't use append, extend

so  `publications.extend(links)` instead if ` publications.append(links)`

Comment: I'm at a complete loss with the second code snippet. I thought puplications is a list of pdfs?

Should you then just do
`for link in publications:   rslt = request.get(link)`
 and Then in the for loop take a tool, that can parse pdf and extract words?

Comment: publications is a list of pdf links.

Comment: also in above code snippets you're using requests, which is in my opinion rather easy to use. In the second section you use urllib.request, which is in my opinion more annoying to use. I'd suggest to stick with requests for easier code.

Comment: To me it looks as if it is a list of lists of pdf links, so it doesn't seem to be a flat list at least if you really used the code that you posted.
you declare an empty list named publications, afterwards you execute a for loop in this for loop you create a list named links, and then you append this list to publications. (Thus list of lists) IF you used extend you would have a flat list.

Comment: I thought I could use the list of pdf links. And then I could use a pdf parser to go through that list, open the links, and then parse through the text. Edit: I've also included the error  I get when I run my code.

Comment: @Leonardo Lima doesn't have enough rep to comment so I comment for him:
Could you please inform also the line number ow where the error occours ?

His comment was taken into account end details errors are shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pls try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import csv

# This code adds all PDF links into a list called 
#"publications".

publications=[]
for i in range(19):
    response=requests.get('https://occ.ca/our- 
   publications/page/{}/'.format(i), headers={'User- 
    Agent': 'Mozilla'})

    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        pdfs = soup.findAll('div', {"class": 
       "publicationoverlay"})
        links = [pdf.find('a').attrs['href'] for pdf in pdfs]
    publications.extend(links)

for cntr, link in enumerate(publications):
    print("try to get link", link)
    rslt = requests.get(link)
    print("Got", rslt)
    fname = "temporarypdf_%d.pdf" % cntr
    with open("temporarypdf_%d.pdf" % cntr, "wb") as fout:
        fout.write(rslt.raw.read())
    print("saved pdf data into ", fname)
    # Call here the code that reads and parses the pdf.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help gelonida. The code works but I'm not sure what it does, as it doesn't seem to have downloaded the PDF files.

Comment: this answer still does not go through the pdf code, but it should at least try to download each pdf.

For going through the text of a pdf file you could use libraries like https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer.six/

Comment: I enhaced the code to save the pdf into temporary files for debugging / testing.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please inform also the line number where the error occours ?

Comment: I'm rather new to Stack Overflow, but shouldn't this better be a comment and not an answer?

Comment: I was not able to give a comment, that was the reason that I write an answer. You have to have 50 points reputation.

Comment: Ah True Didn't see your reps. I forgot this problem , Had the same issue only one or two weeks ago.
However I mentioned in the answer, that it is not an answer, but that I can't comment to reduce confusion.

Comment: I think that is better if I just delete this answer, you solved the problem =)

Comment: In any case, I added your comment to the comment's section. So The more experienced guys can decide whether you should delete this comment, or whether it should be kept, so that we can upvote the comment on your anser, such, that you get a few points closer to a better rep.